# categorical data sequence clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have to perform a clustering of a categorical sequence data set. The data set is a [Time of Use survey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-use_survey) where for each of the person involved in the survey I have a sequence of 144 (one every ten minutes) labels that represent the action that they are perfoming. I want to identify archetypes of users with respect to the pattern and with respect to labels regarding the person (eg. Age, work, Sex, ...). Which clustering technique can I use? Any python libraries?

Comment: for the _python libraries_ part, have you tried [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org)?

Comment: Ok scikit but I have categorical data not numerical so kmeans is not useful. Suggestion for other algorithms?